# what is the differnece between the gpio interrupt and hardware interrupt?

Tags: gpio, linux, interrupts

In raspberry linux, we are using interrupts and gpio interrupts.

Whats the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing significant as far as I am aware.  A gpio interrupt is just a convenient name for an interrupt generated by the gpio hardware.